# How could I optimise this simple function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Lets say I have the following:

```c++
template <class T>
std::string to_string(const T& item)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << item;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Is it possible to create an overload of `to_string` that in the case of being given a `std::string` would simply forward the argument without any overhead?

Comment: Why can't you just create another overload?

Comment: Yes, just overload it. Not sure why you didn't bother trying.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::to_string`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd add a couple of overloads, one that returns a copy of an lvalue `std::string` and another that `move`s an rvalue `std::string`.

```
std::string to_string(const std::string& item)
{
    return item;
}

std::string to_string(std::string&& item)
{
    return std::move(item);
}

std::string s("Hello, World!");
std::cout << to_string(s) << std::endl;  // calls the lvalue overload

std::cout << to_string(std::string("Hello, World!")) << std::endl; // calls the rvalue overload
std::cout << to_string(20) << std::endl; // calls the function template
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a33ed6e48397fc)

---

You could also let [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) do the job for cases where `T` is numeric by tag dispatching to `std::to_string` using [`std::is_arithmetic<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic).

```
template <class T>
std::string to_string_impl(const T& item, std::true_type)
{
    return std::to_string(item);
}

template <class T>
std::string to_string_impl(const T& item, std::false_type)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << item;
    return ss.str();
}

template <class T>
std::string to_string(const T& item)
{
    return to_string_impl(item, std::is_arithmetic<T>{});
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6f95aaee6735ee2)

---

Finally, if you can use boost, your function can be replaced by [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

```
auto str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(whatever);
```

Comment: What benefit does that offer then simply adding `using std::to_string`? Won't the compiler automatically use `std::to_string` when it can then?

Comment: The `std::string` overloads will [not be found](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62288b01ffbaa598) if you add `using std::to_string`, unless you also add a `using ::to_string;` declaration for them.

Comment: @Chris_F I don't think there's any benefit to tag dispatching over that.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to create an overload of `to_string` that in the case of being given a `std::string` ...

Of course.

```
std::string to_string(const std::string& str) {
   return str;
}
```

> ... would simply forward the argument without any overhead?

Not sure what you mean by "forward" here, but...

You could provide another overload on cases where a temporary or `std::move`d object is provided as an argument to `to_string`. Use an r-value reference for that.

```
std::string to_string(std::string&& str) {
   return std::move(str);
}
```

Note that the `std::move` at the return statement is necessary here, as it would result into a copy if it is not used (the compiler treats all named variables as lvalues, and with `str` a named variable, there's the need for `std::move`).

Now you have two versions overloaded for `std::string` the first will effectively return a copy of the provided argument, while the second one takes advantage temporary objects and explicitly `std::move`d objects.

```
std::string str = "Hello World!";
auto str1 = to_string(str);    // *effectively* copies str to str1 [1]
auto str2 = to_string("Hi");   // *effectively* moves the temporary created here [1]
auto str3 = to_string(std::move(str));   // *effectively* moves str to str3; [1]
```

[1] Actually, there still *may* be several additional moves involved when returning, and copy-elision optimizations *may* be applied by the compiler on some cases.

---

**UPDATE**

> Wouldn't `auto str2 = to_string("Hi");` call the template function, as that does not involve an implicit conversion and is therefor the more suitable overload? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544000/how-could-i-optimise-this-simple-function/24544063#comment38010804_24544063)

You're right. With that, you could provide another overload accepting a `const char*`

```
std::string to_string(const char* str) {
   return str;
}
```

or you could document the behavior and let (more like force) users to do `to_string(std::string("bah"))`. I'm pretty sure you'll provide the overload though :-).

Comment: Wouldn't `auto str2 = to_string("Hi");` call the template function, as that does not involve an implicit conversion and is therefor the more suitable overload?

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance, stay away from any `stringstream` stream and its ilks, they're sadly incredibly slow. You're correct that you could just introduce an overload such as `std::string to_string( const std::string& item )`, and it would be a better match and get selected. There's also `boost::lexical_cast`, and perhaps something similar in c++11 ( someone else will have to chip in here ). `boost::lexical_cast` however is also very slow due to its internals relying on `stringstream`. IMO the best way is to introduce your own function, such as you've done with your `to_string`, fallback to `boost::lexical_cast` and specialize / overload for your own types. We specialize a lot of our types using `boost::spirit::qi`, there's performance comparisons out there which rings true with our tests, it's rather easy to  use `boost::spirit::qi` and its parsers to get way better performance characteristics than `stringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you are asking for "Template Specialization".

```
template <class T>
std::string to_string(const T& item)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << item;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string to_string (const string& item)
{
    return item;
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:

In the to_string function we have passed "const string&", therefore function call should be like:

```
string my_string = "ABC";
to_string (my_string);
```

to call the specialized function.

If you call to_string like:

```
to_string ("ABC");
```

then "std::string to_string(const T& item)" general function would be called instead of specialized function.

I hope that this will solve your query.

Comment: Your solution is not Template Specialization, but overloading (which is better BTW). Template Specialization would be `template<> std::string to_string(const string& item)`